# Graphics card not being used on Manjaro with HDMI

Tags: nvidia, manjaro, gpu, hdmi

I honestly couldn't think of a better to way to phrase the title of this, sorry, but here's my issue:

For a long time I ran Antergos on my desktop with no problem, but the today I've installed Manjaro and have had a lot of weird problems, which I think are all related, and so I'll describe them:

- The login/lock screen *only* shows through a HDMI cable.
- If I unplug the HDMI cable, the login screen never shows (I can get to the desktop by typing my password and pressing enter, very hacky), but the issue is that when the HDMI cable isn't in, everything runs super slowly. (By the way, the other cable I want to use is Display Port)
- When I launch applications (I tried minecraft, for example), it uses my integrated Intel graphics, rather than the GPU.

So, this whole thing seems strange. Any thoughts? Thanks!